# Curl with custom certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, openssl, curl

I 'd like curl to work with sites signed by goDaddy:
If I call

```
curl mypage.com/bla
```

I am getting a certificate verification error. I tried getting the ca certificate with this snippet:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect mysite.com:443 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > cert.pem
```

and afterwards calling

```
curl mypage.com/bla --cacert cert.pem
```

which also caused a verification error. I checked the certificate date and subject and everything seems fine?

What am I missing? Do I maybe need the whole chain? If yes, is there a command to get it all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CA in cacert means certification authority. You should specify the cert or cert path of the  authority that signed your certificate, not your certificate itself

the command

> openssl x509  -in  YourSitePemCert  -text

should list an issuer line. you should get the issuer certificate and include it the cacert pem file

( in your case searching godaddy cert chain lead to https://certs.godaddy.com/repository )

Answer (score 11):

According documentation:

> curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a
>   "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the
>   default bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
>   using the `--cacert` option.

If this **HTTPS** server uses a certificate signed by a **CA** represented in the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might not match the domain name in the URL). If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use the `-k (or --insecure)` option.

For goDaddy you must use **SSL Certificate and CA Bundle** (`gd_bundle.crt`). You can download from https://certs.godaddy.com/repository/gd_bundle.crt

**Eg.**

```
curl https://mysite.com --cacert gd_bundle.crt
```